# set input val() to prev().text()

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="parent">
    <span>nameValue</span>    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <span>addressValue</span> <input type="text" value=""/>
    <span>phoneValue</span>   <input type="text" value=""/>
    <span>emailValue</span>   <input type="text" value=""/>

     <div class="edit">Edit</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().find('input').val(v);   // something like var v = $(this).prev().text() ????? 
    });
});
```

i'm trying to set the value of all inputs to the text of their corresponding prev element.
But how can i access it's prev element?

there is no `id` set to the input elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest(".parent").find("input").val(function() {
    return $(this).prev().text();
});
```

You might as well use a `.each` loop and use `val()` on every of them, but the callback function is the cleaner method.

Comment: You're right, I've fixed that. Should've been only done if it is an id.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it as I'm about to go to bed, but this should do the trick for you.

```
$(this).parent().find("input").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).prev().html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){
     $inputs = $(this).parent().find('input');
     $inputs.each(function(){
         var v = $(this).prev("span").text();
         $(this).val(v);                  
     });
});​
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/aN38D/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit').click(function(e){       
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.children('span').each(function(){
            $(this).next().val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

});

Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".parent").find("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).prev().text());
    });
});​
```